# Fetching data from core data using GCD causes issue IOS

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I am developing IOS application in which I am using core data. In my application I am using split view controller. So my split view controller's master view contains following things:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self getNotificationCounter];
    [self getTicketCounter];
}
-(void) getNotificationCounter:(UITableViewCell *) cell
{
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Notification Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"NotificationsData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //update view;
    });
});
}

-(void) getTicketCounter:(UITableViewCell *) cell
{
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Ticket Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

    NSFetchRequest *ticketFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *ticketEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                         entityForName:@"Tickets" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [ticketFetchRequest setEntity:ticketEntity];
    NSError *ticketError = nil;
    NSArray *ticketFetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:ticketFetchRequest error:&ticketError];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update view
       });
});
}
```

and detail view controller have following thing.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“channels” inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"channelId" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

So my problem is like this :
In my detail view controller I have one NSFetchRequestController and in master view have two
two NSFetchRequest with two GCD. if I start my application in portrait mode its works fine. But in landscape mode it stops without giving any error. Another thing If remove one GCD NSFetchRequest from master controller it works fine Or if I remove NSFetechResultController then also it works fine. Why it is so? Am I doing some thing wrong. Need Some help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read anything about core data and multi-threading? Is there a reason you're using GCD?

Comment: If I directly fetch data from core data without using thread it will block UI thread and If I use thread then it will not block

Comment: So in my scenario also I am using same thing

Comment: If it blocks the main thread for too long then your fetch request configuration is generally wrong. On a mobile device the data store shouldn't ever be big enough to cause significant issues. If it is you need to consider your threading carefully.

Comment: yeah But there is nothing wrong in that if you are using it with this situation also.

Comment: Don't really understand your comment. Try without multi-threading and only add if you observe an issue you can't fix with batch fetching. If you do add see the answer from @WarrenBurton

Comment: Yeah @wain sir I tested it without thread and with thread. So when I am using it without thread it will cause bit delay in UI rendering and If i use thread then it works fine. I will try below solution and let you know if it works.

Comment: Set the `fetchBatchSize` to the number of items you see on screen at any one time + 2 to begin with and retest

Comment: I jus want counter for no of items present in entity. Thats it :)

Comment: So you should fetch once, cache it and update it only on insert / delete...

Comment: Yeah but it is notification counter. So I have to keep it updated as well

Answer (score 2):

You may not let `NSManagedObjectContext` or `NSManagedObject` cross threads.

You must create a fresh context for your thread.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Ticket Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
threadContext.parent = context; //assumes other context is NSMainThreadConcurrencyType

    NSFetchRequest *ticketFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *ticketEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                         entityForName:@"Tickets" inManagedObjectContext:threadContext];
    [ticketFetchRequest setEntity:ticketEntity];
...
```

To get `NSManagedObject` between contexts use it's `objectID` property and `[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithId:]`

Should you make edits then you will need to save the thread context. Those changes will propagate automatically down to the parent context.

Otherwise you discard the context at the end of the block like a sheet of paper.

**EDIT**

Also if the count of the objects is the only thing you want then you can use 
`countForFetchRequest:error:` on `NSManagedObjectContext`

This will be a cheaper call because no objects are created for you.

Comment: Hi Warren sir I tried you sir thank you for replay. I am maintaining my object context in app delegate. So i tried in this way `AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext  = [delegate managedObjectContext];` But still same problem.

Comment: @Nilkash: You cannot store the managed object context in the delegate and use it across threads. You must create it *inside* the GCD thread. I suggest you read the `Concurrency with Core Data` guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW6) and implement the shared persistent store with a different managed object context in each thread. Or drop the threads and perform everything on the main thread.

Comment: What the cat said. See that that demo snippet creates a brand new context inside the async block. You MUST do that. You can never pass the context across the thread.